# Converting a dataframe row with multiple date formats into a datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has two rows that need to be in datetime format so I can use them for calculations.

They are currently stored as strings in the formats
mm/dd/yyyy
mm/dd/yy

How can I convert them all into a singular format? I have tried using

`dataframe['ADMISSION_DATE'] =pd.to_datetime(dataframe['ADMISSION_DATE'] , format='%m%d%y').dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`

[Rows that need to be changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6kYs.png)

Comment: If you dont know the format, how do you know whether 10/03/2002 is 10th of March 2002 dd/mm/yyyy or 3rd of October 2022 mm/dd/yyyy? edit: Based on the screenshot provided it might be the case that every date is either mm/dd/yyyy or mm/dd/yy. Could you please check if that holds true for every value in your column?

Comment: You are correct. Every row is of the form mm/dd/yyyy or mm/dd/yy, I edited the question to show this now. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Okay. Did you try the solution I posted?
I added  `dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` in the last row so you know how to transform it into the format you want.

Comment: great :) perhaps you could accept my answer to mark the question as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming my assumption in the comment holds true, you can use this:

```
pd.to_datetime(df["ADMISSION_DATE"], format="%m/%d/%Y", errors="coerce"). \
    fillna(pd.to_datetime(df["ADMISSION_DATE"], format="%m/%d/%y", errors="coerce")).\
    dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

You basically try to convert using the first format and whenever this fails, you try the second format.